# Dynamic schema processor in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, mondrian

I have a working dsp configured with the code below. I also want to retrieve the users roles and use it later in the query. Do anyone knows how to retrieve the roles from the user?

```
public class SubscriptionCountry extends FilterDynamicSchemaProcessorimplements DynamicSchemaProcessor {
private static final String BBDD_HOST = "xxx";
private static final String BBDD_PORT = "xxx";
private static final String BBDD_NAME = "xxx";
private static final String BBDD_USER = "xxx";
private static final String BBDD_PASSWORD = "xxx";
public SubscriptionCountry() {

}
@Override
public String filter(String schemaUrl, Util.PropertyList connectInfo, InputStream stream) throws Exception {
    String schema = super.filter(schemaUrl, connectInfo, stream);

    Connection c = null;
    String country_list = "";

    try {
        // Get Pentaho Session
        IPentahoSession session = PentahoSessionHolder.getSession();

        // Get user from session variable
        String userName = session.getName().toString();

        String query_countries = "";
        query_countries = "SELECT something from a table where username = + userName";

        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://" + BBDD_HOST + ":" + BBDD_PORT + "/" + BBDD_NAME,BBDD_USER, BBDD_PASSWORD);
        Statement st = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query_countries);
        rs.next();
        country_list = rs.getString("country_list");
        rs.close();
        st.close();
    } 
    try {
        schema = schema.replaceAll("%COUNTRY_LIST%", country_list);
    }
    return schema;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have done it in a jsp: I guess it should work for you too :

those are the imports in my jsp (maybe you don't need everything...) :

```
<%@page import="org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.IAuthorizationPolicy" %>
<%@page import="org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.IPluginManager" %>
<%@page import="org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSessionHolder" %>
<%@page import="org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem" %>
<%@page import="org.pentaho.platform.security.policy.rolebased.actions.AdministerSecurityAction" %>
<%@page import="org.pentaho.platform.security.policy.rolebased.actions.RepositoryCreateAction" %>
<%@page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@page import="java.util.Locale"%>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest"%>
<%@page import="org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.IPentahoSession"%>
<%@page import="org.pentaho.platform.engine.security.SecurityParameterProvider"%>
```

Then :

```
SecurityParameterProvider secpro= new SecurityParameterProvider(PentahoSessionHolder.getSession() );
 String listroles = secpro.getStringParameter("principalRoles","aucun");
```

And listroles contains the list of the roles

See also :

http://javadoc.pentaho.com/bi-platform/dev/org/pentaho/platform/engine/security/SecurityParameterProvider.html